# Linq where clause not working when including another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq condition that i include a second table. On the second table i have a where condition to give me records that are not deleted. how ever the where condition is ignored and it returns items that was deleted.

```
var test= (await table1.GetListAsync(q => q.Where(x => x.Name == command.Name && x.Id == command.Id && x.Deleted==false).Include(x => x.Tables2.Where(y => y.Deleted == false)))).FirstOrDefault();
```

in the above code table1 where clause executes correctly but the where clause on table 2 returns deleted records.

Table 1 model looks as follows

```
public class Table1: IdentityModel<string>
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public bool Deleted { get; set; }
   public IList<Table2> Tables2{ get; set; } = new List<Table2>();
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What version of EF are you using or are you using something else?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ doesnt contain `Include` extention method. Seems you are speaking about  EntiryFramework that serves different purposes - eager loading related  fields.

Depending on your requirements, you might want to follow one of the following approaches

1. Filter data in memory

```
var test = (await table1.GetListAsync(q => q.Where(x => x.Name == command.Name && x.Id == command.Id && x.Deleted==false)
    .Include(x => x.Tables2))).FirstOrDefault();

// Now filter in memory
if (test != null)
{
    test.Tables2 = test.Tables2.Where(t => !t.Deleted).ToList();
}
```

2. Use a projection

```
var test = await table1
    .Where(x => x.Name == command.Name && x.Id == command.Id && x.Deleted==false)
    .Select(x => new {
        Table1 = x,
        Tables2 = x.Tables2.Where(y => !y.Deleted)
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It's not entirely clear what data you want to fetch, but you can use the code abot as starting point.